# Python KeyError: for x_col value in flow_from_dataframe for referencing existing column

Tags: python, dataframe, tensorflow

My code below is as follows:

```py
   train_generator = aug.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe = z1,
                                              directory = None,
                                              x_col = 'id',
                                              y_col = 'label',
                                              class_mode = 'categorical',
                                              target_size = (mysize, mysize),
                                              shuffle = True,
                                              batch_size = mybatch,
                                              seed = 40)
    val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
    val_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(z2,
                                                   x_col = 'id',
                                                   y_col = 'label',
                                                   class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                   target_size = (mysize, mysize),
                                                   batch_size = mybatch,
                                                   seed = 41)
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
    test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(testfiles,
                                                     x_col = 'id',
                                                     directory = None,
                                                     color_mode = 'rgb',
                                                     target_size = (mysize, mysize),
                                                     batch_size = 1,
                                                     class_mode = None,
                                                     shuffle = False,
                                                     seed = 42)
```

I have checked, and my DataFrames `z1`, `z2` and `testfiles` all have a column within that is labeled `id`. Here's the `head()` for each of these:

```
z1.head()

Output:
label   id
0   0.0 train/cat.5077.jpg
1   0.0 train/cat.2718.jpg
2   0.0 train/cat.10151.jpg
3   0.0 train/cat.3406.jpg
4   0.0 train/cat.4369.jpg

z2.head()

Output:
label   id
6   0.0 train/cat.8553.jpg
7   0.0 train/cat.9895.jpg
9   0.0 train/cat.6218.jpg
11  0.0 train/cat.12020.jpg
17  0.0 train/cat.10637.jpg

testfiles.head()

Output:
    id
```

`testfiles` is an empty DataFrame but it does contain a column with name `id`.

So it's very confusing that I'm getting a `KeyError`, which displays as following:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2656             try:
-> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'id'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-2a56a9e3c4bf> in <module>
     40                                                      class_mode = None,
     41                                                      shuffle = False,
---> 42                                                      seed = 42)

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py in flow_from_dataframe(self, dataframe, directory, x_col, y_col, weight_col, target_size, color_mode, classes, class_mode, batch_size, shuffle, seed, save_to_dir, save_prefix, save_format, subset, interpolation, validate_filenames, **kwargs)
    592             interpolation=interpolation,
    593             validate_filenames=validate_filenames,
--> 594             **kwargs
    595         )
    596 

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py in __init__(self, dataframe, directory, image_data_generator, x_col, y_col, weight_col, target_size, color_mode, classes, class_mode, batch_size, shuffle, seed, data_format, save_to_dir, save_prefix, save_format, subset, interpolation, dtype, validate_filenames)
    233             interpolation=interpolation,
    234             dtype=dtype,
--> 235             validate_filenames=validate_filenames)
    236 
    237 

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras_preprocessing/image/dataframe_iterator.py in __init__(self, dataframe, directory, image_data_generator, x_col, y_col, weight_col, target_size, color_mode, classes, class_mode, batch_size, shuffle, seed, data_format, save_to_dir, save_prefix, save_format, subset, interpolation, dtype, validate_filenames)
    144         if class_mode not in ["input", "multi_output", "raw", None]:
    145             self.classes = self.get_classes(df, y_col)
--> 146         self.filenames = df[x_col].tolist()
    147         self._sample_weight = df[weight_col].values if weight_col else None
    148 

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

//anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2658             except KeyError:
-> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2660         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'id'
```

Does anybody know what is going on here? From what I understand, `KeyError` occurs when referencing a value that isn't contained within a dictionary, i.e. a column that does not exist.

From what I understand a similar problem is referenced in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58165203/keyerror-class-while-using-imagedatagenerator-flow-from-dataframe), but did not appear to be solved:

Answer (score 0):

**Image Data Generator** first **validates** the files in your **DataFrame** whether they **all exist**, thus raising `Key error` if there is nothing to validate.

If you inspect your error trace log.

```
# get labels for each observation
        if class_mode not in ["input", "multi_output", "raw", None]:
            self.classes = self.get_classes(df, y_col)
        self.filenames = df[x_col].tolist()    <<< ERROR HERE
        self._sample_weight = df[weight_col].values if weight_col else None
```

This **converts** all the values contained in the DataFrame `df` into a **list**.

Thus, If you dig a little further.

```
if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
                return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
            indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)   <<< ERROR HERE
            if is_integer(indexer):
                indexer = [indexer]
```

You could see that the line, that the `key` in the `column` is the index used for references.
Passing an Empty Array `[]` is guaranteed to raise an error as you will be using `Nothing` as a reference.

And also, the Image Data Generator just **returns the value**, meaning it will be useless when you feed it Empty Array.
For this, you could try to create a DataFrame with Empty String `testfiles = pd.DataFrame([''], columns = ['id'])` to avoid encountering the `Key Error`.